# Webpack is choosing the minified version of a library

Tags: webpack

I am trying to bundle a code that uses `esquery` library. So in a part of the code I have `require("esquery")`.
My code is broken after being bundled. I tracked the exception and it says `Parse is not a function`. However the function does exist in the library.

I noticed that webpack is choosing the minfied version of the library `__webpack_require__(/*! esquery */ "./node_modules/esquery/dist/esquery.esm.min.js")`.
After deleting the `esquery.esm.min.js` file. Webpack produced the following code `__webpack_require__(/*! esquery */ "./node_modules/esquery/dist/esquery.min.js")` (without `esm` extension). and the code worked like a charm.

I am wondering why webpack is choosing the minified versions, and whether or not I control this behavior.

In the package.json of the library there is `"module": "dist/esquery.esm.min.js"` which I guess tells webpack which file to use as a module. Deleting this line also solved the problem.
It may be a build issue of the library. But as far as I know webpack always bundles the source version. and I can't get to find a documentation concerning that.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem?  I'm also facing with it.

Comment: I kept deleting the `.esm.min.js` file manually